# get the source domain from a post request

Tags: apex, integration, httprequest, post

Third-party need to send Data to Salesforce using Https post request - They cant handle token access so it must be a force.com site.

I referred an Apex class to the site (Without using VF page), by taking the URL of the site and add the /services/apexrest/< nameOfTheClass >.

I want to know -

I there a way to get from Apex (not JS) the URL of the third-party who tried to get the service?

I need this URL because they cant supply an IP, and they want us to handle the access by the source domain from the URL...

What are the disadvantages of using a URL instead of an IP address?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use a domain from which a request originates as a way of "authentication", as a it doesn't provide any means of security and can easily be bypassed.

IP whitelisting is indeed the more secure way to go, as even though an IP address from which a request is sent CAN be spoofed, it will never receive any data back, since it will be sent back to the "legitimate" client with that particular IP address.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response.
And although all, there is a way to check the URL domain within apex? I just want to know if there is any method that can have this data on the sender.

Comment: It is still not clear for me, what you mean by URL? You can get all the HTTP request headers using [this approach](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158047/unable-to-get-request-header-details). Using [URLClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_url.htm), allows you to get details on the URL/Domain of your org.

Comment: I would like to have data about the sender URL.
I didn't see any method from the URLClass that provide the data about the sender.

Comment: This is why you need to check the headers, looking for 'referer'-header value. I am still concerned about your approach to security, and will strongly discourage this practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I will not use the URL approach. I took your advice as the best practice - I just wanted to know if there a way to achieve it via apex.
Thanks again :)